# Can TChart create a cylinder/pipe/tube with surface coloring similar to the TColorGridSeries

Tags: delphi, pipe, teechart

Environment
 RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin using Delphi
 TeeChart Pro v2017.22 170619
 IntraWeb 14.1.14

I am creating a Web Page using IntraWeb to display various images. One of these,  recently requested, is a 3D pipe/tube image with a surface color contour/gradient that I control as shown in the following concept image:

[image: Pipe Concept Image].

I need to be able to rotate, pan and zoom this image. I am hoping there is a way to implement this using TeeChart.

As far as I am able to determine TChart only supports surface meshes and not a 3D surface on an object.

I would like to use TeeChart but am open to other possibilities. I have looked for other components that may support this but have not been able to find any.

I have looked at possible using FMX but IntraWeb is a VCL application. I know that FMX has been used in VCL so this is a possibility. However if this is possible I am not sure if it is possible to create the pipe with a color surface contour/gradient.

Answer (score 0):

About the interactivity, if you want to rotate the series (not the image) I'm not sure if you can forward the events from Intraweb to the Chart to rotate it.

- An option would be to use the `TVoluemPipeSeries`. Ie:

  ```
  uses TeeGLCanvas, TeeVolumePipe;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Chart1.Canvas:=TGLCanvas.Create;

    Chart1.Legend.Visible:=False;
    Chart1.Chart3DPercent:=100;
    Chart1.Aspect.Orthogonal:=False;
    Chart1.Aspect.Rotation:=230;

    with Chart1.AddSeries(TVolumePipeSeries) as TVolumePipeSeries do
    begin
      FillSampleValues;
      Pen.Color:=Chart1.Canvas.ColorFrom(Pen.Color,150);
    end;
  end;
  ```

[image: VolumePipe]

- Another option is to use two `TSurfaceSeries`. Ie:

  ```
  uses TeeSurfa, Math;

  var topSurface, bottomSurface: TSurfaceSeries;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var nRev, countZ, i, z: Integer;
      alpha, x, y: Double;
  begin
    Chart1.Legend.Visible:=False;
    Chart1.Chart3DPercent:=100;
    Chart1.Aspect.Orthogonal:=False;
    Chart1.Aspect.Zoom:=80;
    Chart1.Aspect.Rotation:=320;
    Chart1.Aspect.Elevation:=350;
    Chart1.Walls.Visible:=False;
    Chart1.Axes.Visible:=False;

    nRev:=50;
    countZ:=20;

    bottomSurface:=Chart1.AddSeries(TSurfaceSeries) as TSurfaceSeries;
    topSurface:=Chart1.AddSeries(TSurfaceSeries) as TSurfaceSeries;

    topSurface.IrregularGrid:=True;
    topSurface.XValues.Order:=loNone;
    topSurface.YValues.Order:=loNone;
    topSurface.Pen.Color:=Chart1.Canvas.ColorFrom(bottomSurface.Pen.Color,150);

    bottomSurface.IrregularGrid:=True;
    bottomSurface.XValues.Order:=loNone;
    bottomSurface.YValues.Order:=loNone;
    bottomSurface.Pen.Color:=Chart1.Canvas.ColorFrom(bottomSurface.Pen.Color,150);

    for z:=0 to countZ-1 do
    begin
      for i:=0 to nRev-1 do
      begin
        alpha:=DegToRad(i*360/nRev);
        x:=Cos(alpha);
        y:=Sin(alpha);

        if alpha<DegToRad(180) then
          topSurface.AddXYZ(x, y, z, '', RGB(random(255), random(255), random(255)))
        else
          bottomSurface.AddXYZ(x, y, z, '', RGB(random(255), random(255), random(255)));
      end;

      bottomSurface.AddXYZ(topSurface.XValues.MaxValue, Sin(ArcCos(topSurface.XValues.MaxValue)), z, '', RGB(random(255), random(255), random(255)));
      bottomSurface.AddXYZ(topSurface.XValues.MinValue, Sin(ArcCos(topSurface.XValues.MinValue)), z, '', RGB(random(255), random(255), random(255)));
    end;
  end;
  ```

[image: Surfaces]

Comment: The TeeVolumePipe was quite slow in rendering compared to the two surfaces also I could not see a way to get the gradient colors. How do I get the two surfaces to show a smooth gradient between colors to get the contour effect I had in my original image?

Comment: The `TVoluemPipeSeries` example above is slow because of OpenGL initialization. When that has been done, it's fast.

Comment: In the example I've set random colors to the `TSurfaceSeries` cells. You could set use your palette to set the colors as you want